# How do I getActiveRange() for 2 columns separated by a gap. I.E: E10:E14 and G10:G14?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been trying to create a booking system in Google App Script that allows the user to select a series of locations they are interested to book from the spreadsheet.

Once the range is selected, for example E10:E14 and G10:G14, I would need to use those range to do some colouring.

I tried using getActiveRange() but it just gives me G10:G14. Please help.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I think that you should make a feature request on the [Google Apps Script issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222)

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for replying again! Yes I have sent a feature request in regards to this. Apparently it has already been requested a few years back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Making Multiple Selections with a Modeless Dailog

This script allows you to make multiple selections with a simple modeless dialog.

To make it easy to use, I've included a menu.

> 1. Open up a new spreadsheet and go the the script editor.
> 2. Copy the code section into the Code.gs file.
> 3. Copy the html section into the file named searchdialog.hmtl. Note: program creates the html for you.
> 4. From the script editor run startSelectionMenu().  You will have to authorize it.
> 5. Now go to the spreadsheet and open the menu.  Run the first item which is called "Create Pages and Named Ranges.
> 6. Now run the second item which is called "Start Selecting" follow the instructions on the dialog.
> 7. You selections will be found in the sheet named 'Data'.

Filename: Code.gs:

```
function startSelectionMenu(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
      .addItem('1. Create Pages and Named Ranges', 'createMySheetsandNamedRanges')
      .addItem('2. Start Selecting', 'showSelectRangesDailog')
      .addToUi();
}

function getMyRangeColors(r){
  var colors={Range1:'#d9ead3',Range2:'#fff2cc',Range3:'#f4cccc',Range4:'#c9daf8',Range5:'#fce5cd'};
  return colors[r];
}

function getMyColorRanges(c){
  var ranges={'#d9ead3':'Range1','#fff2cc':'Range2','#f4cccc':'Range3','#c9daf8':'Range4','#fce5cd':'Range5'};
  return ranges[c];
}

function colorMyRanges() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rgs=ss.getNamedRanges();
  for(var i=0;i<rgs.length;i++)
  {
    rgs[i].getRange().setBackground(getMyRangeColors(rgs[i].getName()))
  }
}

function selectRangesDialog(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Selections');
  ss.getSheetByName('Data').clear();
  var s='';
  var br='<br />';
  s+=br + 'Please select a range by clicking a color on the spreadsheet and then clicking the Select button.';
  s+=br + '<input type="button" value="Select" onClick="selectRange();" />';
  s+=br + '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" style="margin:10px 0 0 0"/>';
  return s;
}

function addRangeToList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  var ds=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var dr=ds.getDataRange();
  var dA=dr.getValues();
  var selected=[];
  var selection=getMyColorRanges(cell.getBackground());
  for(var i=0;i<dA.length;i++){
    selected.push(dA[i][0]);
  }
  if(selected.indexOf(selection)==-1){
    ds.appendRow([getMyColorRanges(cell.getBackground())]);
    return 'Selection was Added<br />Current Selections: ' + getCurrentSelections();
  }else{
    return 'Selection is Duplicate<br />Current Selections: ' + getCurrentSelections();
  }
}

function showSelectRangesDailog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('selectdialog').setWidth(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Select Ranges');
}

function getCurrentSelections(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  rg.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var curr=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    curr.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return curr.join(', ');
}

function createMySheetsandNamedRanges(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=['Selections','Data'];
  var names=['Range1','Range2','Range3','Range4','Range5'];
  var ranges=['A1:A5','B1:B5','C1:C5','D1:D5','E1:E5'];
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++){
    if(!isSheet(shts[i])){
      ss.insertSheet(shts[i]);
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    var range=shts[0]+'!'+ranges[i];
    createNamedRange(range,names[i]);
  }
  colorMyRanges();
  ss.getSheetByName('Selections').activate();
}

function isSheet(sheetname){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allShts=ss.getSheets();
  var r=false;
  for(var i=0;i<allShts.length;i++){
    if(allShts[i].getName()==sheetname){
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function createSheet(shtname){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isSheet(shtname)){
     ss.insertSheet(shtname);
   }
}

function isRange(rangename){
  var r=false;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rgs=ss.getNamedRanges();
  for(var i=0;i<rgs.length;i++){
    if(rgs[i].getName()==rangename){
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}


function createNamedRange(rangeA1,name)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range=ss.getRange(rangeA1);
  if(!isRange(name)){
    ss.setNamedRange(name, range); 
  }
}

function deleteAllRanges(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rgs=ss.getNamedRanges();
  for(var i=0;i<rgs.length;i++){
    rgs[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Filename: searchdialog.html(the name is important don't change it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(upDateSD1)
        .selectRangesDialog();
  });
  function selectRange(){
    google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(upDateSD2)
       .addRangeToList();

  }
  function selectDone(){
  }
  function upDateSD1(hl){
    $('#sd1').html(hl);
  }
  function upDateSD2(hl){
    $('#sd2').html(hl);
  }
  console.log('MyCode');
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="sd1"></div>
  <div id="sd2"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Terribly sorry for the late response.
Thank you so very much for the answer!