# How can I link the current Google Doc to a new Google Doc named with the text on the line where the cursor is currently located?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's a sample use case.

1. Let say I were typing in Google Doc #1, and then
2. I were to decide that I would like to create a link in Google Doc #1 to a new Google Doc (which does not yet exist).
3. Furthermore, let's say I would this new Google Doc (which does not yet exist) to be named "Cherry pie."
4. Therefore, while I was in Google Doc #1, I would type "Cherry pie", and then
5. I would run the script.
6. As a result, in Google Doc #1 the line where the cursor is currently located (which consists of "Cherry pie") would now be hyperlinked to the Google Doc (which the script just created) named "Cherry pie."

When I run the script below in Google Doc #1, it creates a new Google Doc (Google Doc #2). The script names Google Doc #2 with the text of the line where the cursor is currently located in Google Doc #1.

For example, if the cursor is on a line in Google Doc #1 with the text "Cheese pizza", then the script will create a new Google Doc named "Cheese pizza."

In addition to what the script currently does, I would like the script to also create a hyperlink from "Cheese pizza" (on the line where the cursor is currently located) in Google Doc #1 to Google Doc #2 (which is the document the script will create) with the name "Cheese pizza."

---

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('NewDoc')
    .addItem('Create', 'newDocWithSentense')
    .addToUi();
}

function newDocWithSentense() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const cursor = doc.getCursor();
  const surroundings = cursor.getSurroundingText().getText();

  const currentFileFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getParents().next()
  const newDoc = DocumentApp.create(surroundings).getId()
  DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc).moveTo(currentFileFolder)
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to go to a menu and launch a function that creates a dialog that provides you with the ui to create the new document.  From there you can build your dialog in html and communicate between  the client and server with google.script.run.   It would be valuable for you to have a good understand of Ecma Script 2015.  Here's an [example of a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501625/7215091)

Comment: Thanks but I am a confused. I looked at [How do I getActiveRange() for 2 columns separated by a gap. I.E: E10:E14 and G10:G14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477981/how-do-i-getactiverange-for-2-columns-separated-by-a-gap-i-e-e10e14-and-g10/47501625#47501625) I don't see what I would need any of that. I'm not being snarky; rather I'm being frank. Why would I need a UI to create a new document? If I type "Cheese pizza" on a line in a Google Doc, and then run the script, I want a link created to the new Google Doc named "Cheese pizza".  Aaron Dunigan AtLee solved it for me down below.

Comment: You can do what you wish but I would prefer being able to provide a name for the new doc and possibly even  specify the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [`Text.setLinkUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setlinkurlurl)

Since [`cursor.getSurroundingText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#getSurroundingText()) returns a `Text` object, you can add this line at the end of your existing code:

```
cursor.getSurroundingText().setLinkUrl(DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc).getUrl())
```